# Personalize workflow message "Contributions - Receipt (on-line)"

Tags: civicontribute, system-workflow-messages

Using the action "Confirmation receipt - print or email" in a list of contributions, the message sent to the donateur seems to be "Contributions - Receipt (on-line)".

When adding manually a contribution and checking the "Automatically send a confirmation?" button, the workflow message is "Contributions - Receipt (off-line)".

We personalized the "off-line" message. How to copy this to the "on-line" message? Simply copy and paste does not give a good result. Other form/database values are used.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just copy it to the on-line message.  You will need to start with the current on-line message and customise it in the same way that you did the off-line one.  Those are awkward templates to work with but if you just make small changes you should be ok.

Comment: We tried also to start from the default "on-line" message. https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28507/smarty-does-not-display-database-fields. The problem here is we cannot display the database values "source" and "paidBy" as we did easily on the "off-line" message. The "on-line" message start from a query result, the "off-line" from a webform.

Comment: If you don't have all the variables you want, you can use the api from within the template to get them.  See eg https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/8997/225